# My car stutters when accelerating from 3rd gear

Tags: vw, gti

Hi there I own a 2003 Volkswagen GTi manual 1.8T. Lately my car has been stuttering when in 3rd gear around 2,500 RPM. Usually the turbo spools at that RPM but instead my car is stuttering, this also happens in 4th gear. I have no idea why this is happening (first time Volkswagen owner). ANY help would be gladly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked anything yet? There could be a number of things that would affect the turbo's function which would result in reduced power (low enough power to stutter/jerk around). Any additional data you can give with help us. :)

Comment: Are there any engine codes?

Comment: Does it run normally in the other gears? If you wait to shift into 3rd at a higher RPM, does it happen?

Comment: @Paulster2 yes there is a misfire for cylinder 1. I was thinking maybe to replace spark plugs? I am going to the dealer to get ignition coils replaced because of a recall.

Comment: @David Lively first gear and second gear do not seem to be affected as far as I can tell. Yes if I shift at a higher RPM the problem still happens.

Comment: @kyle_engineer I have not checked anything. I had no idea where to start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 1.8T engine VT used in this age of car did have an extremely common issue with the coilpacks failing and producing a misfire on the cylinder with the failed pack. As you mention in your comment there is a recall for these where the dealer will replace them with an updated version that (mostly) prevents the problem recurring.

Comment: From what you've described I'd be surprised if it wasn't the classic coilpack issue.. it was so common on that engine that I knew owners who used to drive around with spares in the boot of the car!

Answer (score -1):

I went to the dealership and they installed the ignition coil pack. Hooray! But now I need the following arts for my car. 1. Secondary air pump. 2. Rear O2 sensor. 3. New spark plugs. Also I was told to flush my coolant and brake fluid. Can anyone tell me where I can buy this parts? Preferably OEM? The dealer says that OEM parts are better because they work best with the car. Please help? Please provide a website or shop.

Comment: Once you wander into the realm of asking for parts assistance, the question becomes off-topic for the site. If this is the original answer for your question, then so be it, but we won't be able to answer your newer question.